# SQL loop for updating rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server. The scenario is the following:

I have a csv with a bunch of Serial N0, which are unique.

Example:

```
Serial No
-----------
01561
21654
156416
89489
```

I also have a SQL Server database table, where are several rows which can be identified with the serial no. For example I have 6 rows in the SQL Server table with the serial no. 01561. Now I want to update a field in all these rows with "Yes". If it is only about this number, I know the solution it's

```
UPDATE dbo.Table1 
SET DeleteFlag =  'Yes' 
WHERE Serial No. = 01561;
```

Unfortunately I have more than 10,000 Serial No in the csv for what I have to do that. Can you help me to find a solution for that?

Comment: Seems like you're after an `EXISTS`.

Comment: Load them into a temp table or table variable then do a simple join or exists check

Answer (score 0):

First you should use the TASK feature to import the CSV. You right click to do this on the database and select "TASK" and import data. Its a UI which is pretty self explanatory, so itll help you get the job done quickly and easily. Make note of the name you give the table, SQL Server will try and give it a defualt name with a "$" in the name. Change that to something like "MyTableImport". If the data is already in SQL Server, go to the next step.

Step 2 - You can do the UPDATE for the entire table via a join. All youre doing is matching the ID's to another table, right? Looping would be a bad idea here especially since itll take a minute to loop through 10000+ and run an update FOR EACH ONE. Thats against an idea known as "Set based approach" which to sum it up nicely is to do things all at once (google it  though because im horribly over simplifying the idea for you). Here is a sample update join query for you:

```
UPDATE x
SET x.DeleteFlag='Yes'
FROM yourimportable y 
INNER JOIN yourLocal x ON y.SerialNo=x.SerialNo
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created a `temp table` to load CSV with a bunch of serial number. Now you can update your permanent table with the `temp table` data using `update join` like this:

```
  UPDATE t1
  SET t1.DeleteFlag = 'Yes' 
  FROM dbo.Table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN #TempTable2 AS t2
  ON t1.Serial_No = t2.Serial_No
```

Comment: I tried this and it works perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If it really works then you may accept this answer :)